# Hide messages in chat which are older than the timestamp in a different table

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have the following database structure for a chat system:

Please see fiddle below

```sql
conversations  
+-----------------+
| COLUMN_NAME     |
+-----------------+
| conversation_id |
| name            |
| created_at      |
| updated_at      |
+-----------------+
```

```sql
conversation_participants
+-----------------+
| COLUMN_NAME     |
+-----------------+
| id              |
| user_id         |
| conversation_id |
| deleted_at      |
+-----------------+
```

```sql
messages
+-----------------+
| COLUMN_NAME     |
+-----------------+
| message_id      |
| user_id         |
| conversation_id |
| message         |
| created_at      |
| updated_at      |
+-----------------+
```

I also fetch the last x messages according to this suggestion https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Now I need to fetch only the messages which are newer that the timestamp `deleted_at` which can be `null`.

Since I use Laravels eager loading I struggle to adjust the query to work without a specific `conversation_id`.

I need to include the last x messages in the query. It also works if I only fetch a specific conversation

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `messages`.*,
        @rank := IF(
            @group = conversation_id,
            @rank +1,
            1
        ) AS rank_bae5f28cab9179ba9b470ec66ec93b7b,
        @group := conversation_id AS group_bae5f28cab9179ba9b470ec66ec93b7b
    FROM
        (
    SELECT
        @rank := 0,
        @group := 0
    ) AS vars,
    messages,
    (
    SELECT
        IFNULL(
            deleted_at,
            '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ) AS deleted_at
    FROM
        conversation_participants
    WHERE
        conversation_participants.conversation_id = 84 AND conversation_participants.user_id = 1
    LIMIT 1
) AS deleted_at
WHERE
    messages.created_at > deleted_at
ORDER BY
    `conversation_id` ASC,
    `created_at`
DESC
) AS messages
WHERE
    `rank_bae5f28cab9179ba9b470ec66ec93b7b` <= 15 AND `messages`.`conversation_id` IN (84)
```

Then I tried to use a join in this subquery to include the 'deleted_at' timestamp

```sql
SELECT
        IFNULL(
            deleted_at,
            '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        ) AS deleted_at
    FROM
        conversation_participants
    JOIN 
        messages
    ON
        conversation_participants.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id
    WHERE
        conversation_participants.user_id = 1
    LIMIT 1
```

but I always receive `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` in the `deleted` value.

So how can I fetch the latest messages and filter them if the `deleted_at` value isn't `null` ?

**EDIT:**

To clarify: 
I have to use this query

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `messages`.*,
        @rank := IF(
            @group = conversation_id,
            @rank +1,
            1
        ) AS rank_bae5f28cab9179ba9b470ec66ec93b7b,
        @group := conversation_id AS group_bae5f28cab9179ba9b470ec66ec93b7b
    FROM
        (
    SELECT
        @rank := 0,
        @group := 0
    ) AS vars,
    messages

ORDER BY
    `conversation_id` ASC,
    `created_at`
DESC
) AS messages
WHERE
    `rank_bae5f28cab9179ba9b470ec66ec93b7b` <= 15
```

so Laravel only fetches the given amount of messages, in this example: 15.
I know that I could do a loop, get the timestamp and filter it that way, but this would result in a n+2 query issue.

I need a way to apply a join for the currently logged in user where the timestamp is to filter the last messages.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is an example fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3W2E99RYDPyebBYxcM1xyo/4

Comment: To be sure. You want the last 10 messages a user is involved and that are not deleted (delete IS NULL)?

Comment: Correct. The last 10 messages of a conversation where 
messages.created_at > conversation_participants.deleted_at. If delete is NULL it should not filter any messages

Comment: rank_bae5f28cab9179ba9b470ec66ec93b7b?

Comment: @Strawberry Variables names generated by php with a hash based on the time and the user_id

Comment: But how/why is that useful ? It just seems to make the query (and question) less comprehensible

Comment: @Strawberry so I can fetch any amount of messages I want. Please see this article https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/ for further details

Comment: Anyway, perhaps see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Added a fiddle to test it better